# Git Workflow for Tracking HPC and Local Analysis Files?

Tags: r, bash, git, github, hpc

I'm new to Git and need advice on the best workflow for managing version control for files on an HPC cluster and my local machine.

My routine is run scripts on HPC -> take the result file to my laptop -> analyse using R.
My R files on laptop is tracked (Github) but not the scripts on the HPC.

How can I track the scripts as well?

Considering:

**HPC Branch:**
Create a branch for HPC scripts.
Unsure if it's the right approach due to different files in HPC vs local.
**Two Repositories:**
Separate repos for HPC scripts and local analysis files on Github.
Unsure about efficiency.

Whats the best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to have both your HPC scripts (shell scripts and R scripts) and your downstream analysis scripts (R scripts and possibly shell scripts to copy files back to laptop) in a GitHub repo. Whether it is one repo or two is your choice that depends on whether they share some code components.

The optimal workflow is to edit scripts only on your laptop, `commit` and `push` to GitHub. Then `pull` on the HPC login node from GirHub. At this point you can submit the HPC shell scripts to run your R scripts.

I typically manage the HPC output files outside GitHub by directly copying them back to my laptop with `scp` or similar tool. This is because HPC output can include large pdf or png files, which do not work well with git version control and result in very large repos. Many debugging iterations result in files that are best replaced rather than version-controlled.

So the important part is that you make this a one-way workflow. Code goes laptop -> GitHub -> HPC cluster. HPC output goes HPC -> laptop, replacing previous output. There is  never a `commit` and `push` from the HPC cluster to GitHub. You can also `pull` your downstream analysis scripts from GitHub to the HPC cluster and run them there.

It is important to set up ssh keys on GitHub (for your laptop and for the HPC login nodes) so that the `push` and `pull` conveniently does not request GitHub logins and just works.

This can all be managed with RStudio, so your editing happens in RStudio on your laptop with all of its familiarity, syntax checking, and convenience. Also, you are in control of all your scripts on your laptop with quick turnaround of git to ship them to any HPC cluster.